# Using python module as an object

Tags: python, class, module, physics

I have created a working simulation in python which is written like:

```
alpha = 5

def f(x):
    """
    Returns value from function
    """
    return alpha*x**2

def g(x):
    """
    Returns another value
    """
    return f(10)*alpha + 4
```

The problem with it is that each time I have some other alpha I have to edit the file. In order to avoid of that I am trying to use classes and the edited code is:

```
class Myclass():

    def __init__(self,alpha):
        """
        Asign alpha for class instance
        """
        self.alpha = alpha

    def f(self,x):
        """
        Returns value from function
        """
        alpha = self.alpha

        return alpha*x**2

    def g(self,x):
        """
        Returns another value
        """
        alpha = self.alpha
        f =  self.f

        return f(10)*alpha + 4
```

Which could be used as:

```
inst = Myclass(4)
inst.g(5) # Getting the function value
inst.f(5) # Also testing of used functions is needed
```

what is the desired behavior.

The problem comes that I have to edit my working simulation code in a way that:

- For each function under **Myclass** I need to write additional argument **self**
- Assigning values for local variables from Myclass object also is needed

How to avoid of these edits? Maybe there are some decorator which does what I want to achieve?

### Edit

Additional keyword arguments is not handy in this situations since I then need to keep track of these parameters from function to function. Usually it works to nest the code in another function, but in this time I explicitly need speed and testing.

### Edit 2

I almost got my desired behavior how I could use my working simulation. After long hours of searching in Google I remembered that in python `Classes` were introduced somehow related to `Modules`. Therefore I thought to use it as some kind of object.

Firstly I leave my simulation alone in some file named `mymodule.py` which I use as module from another file as:

```
class Myclass():    

    def __init__(self,alpha):
        """
        Asign alpha for class instance
        """
        import mymodule
        mymodule.alpha = alpha        
        self.f = mymodule.f
        self.g = mymodule.g
```

which works with given examples. However it raises an undesired behavior:

```
inst = Myclass(5)
inst.g(5)
# 2504
inst_another = Myclass(6)
inst.g(5)
# 3604
```

or simply the `Class` instances are not independent. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `alpha` to both functions as an argument. In this case I've given `alpha` a default value of `5` but that is not necessary. You can just define both functions with `x, alpha` if you want.

```
def f(x, alpha=5):
    """
    Returns value from function
    """
    return alpha*x**2

def g(x, alpha=5):
    """
    Returns another value
    """
    return f(10)*alpha + 4
```

Example using the default alpha value of 5:

```
>>> g(5)
2504

>>> f(5)
125
```

Another where the alpha is 2 for `g()` and 1 for `f()`:

```
>>> g(5, alpha=2)
1004

>>> f(5, 1)
25
```

And if you have many `alphas`

```
>>> alpha_list = [7, 11, 13, 2, 1, 3, 5, 14, 4, 0, 6, 10, 9, 12, 8]
>>> [(f(5, x), g(5, x)) for x in alpha_list] 
[(175, 3504),
 (275, 5504),
 (325, 6504),
 (50, 1004),
 (25, 504),
 (75, 1504),
 (125, 2504),
 (350, 7004),
 (100, 2004),
 (0, 4),
 (150, 3004),
 (250, 5004),
 (225, 4504),
 (300, 6004),
 (200, 4004)]
```

Comment: I have many alphas. It is not handy to write long expressions with my defined function in that way.

Comment: You might have many alphas but in the function you just use one.

Comment: What is the problem? You can pass any alpha to these functions now. In your class example you can only have one.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, you don't have to "Assign values for local variables from Myclass object"

```
class Myclass():

    def __init__(self,alpha):
        self.alpha = alpha

    def f(self,x):
        return self.alpha*x**2

    def g(self,x):
        return self.f(10)*self.alpha + 4
```

Comment: I want to adapt the working simulation as painlessly I can. This type of edit is prone to introduce new bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You may have function that gets both parameters as args

```
def realf(x, alpha):
    """
    Returns value from function
    """
    return alpha*x**2
```

And then you may set default `alpha`, so that it'll look like as a function with one argument.

```
f5 = functools.partial(realf, alpha = 5)
...
f7 = functools.partial(realf, alpha = 7)
```